# How to implement HttpGet for android client?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, api

I am developing client-server application. The server side is asp.net web api. I did simple web api application and simple android client. When I set up web api it works. And I get json. But how I can get data from my clietn application? I conncted my Android-device and trying to get data via WI-FI from my web api. For web api I create a seld hosting.

```
       protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://124.18.240.169:3890/api/values/1/");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String page = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(page);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It is my web api
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://124.18.240.169:3890");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    where 
    124.18.240.160 is my IP whcih i found  in ipconfig. What I should to do (I tried to do like
    http://localhost) but it not wrok for Android app
```

Comment: `Warran` have you considered a google search here is an article that may help [Internet and Cloud Services Android](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263212.aspx)

Comment: check your windows firewall settings provided that your device & test pc are connected to the same private network. When you allow inbound http traffic you can access the service on your ip

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a library to help handle async callbacks. It can be super helpful for this.

This is the one I usually use:

**[LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)**

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too. I've used it in all my apps and haven't had any problems yet!

Hopefully this helps.